# flock doesn't get released on logout/reboot

Tags: linux, bash, shell, locking, flock

I'm using `flock` to try to ensure that only one instance of my script can run at a time. Most of the time this seems to work fine; but when I log out (I use i3wm) or when the PC is rebooted, the lock doesn't get released; on the next login the lock file will still exist and the script fails to start because it cannot acquire a new lock.

As you can see, I already tried `trap` to release the lock on process exit, but that doesn't help.

Am I using `flock` incorrectly or am I missing something else? I was under the impression that the lock should get released when the process ends, so that should include logout/reboot.

```
LOCK_FILE="${HOME}/.my_script.lock"

release_lock() {
    # This shouldn't be necessary but it seems
    # the lock doesn't release on i3 exit
    rm "${LOCK_FILE}"
}


(
    if [[ -n $LOGFILE ]]; then
        exec >>"$LOGFILE" 2>&1
    fi

    flock -xn 200 || { show_message "$(basename ${0}): cannot acquire lock ${LOCK_FILE}"; exit 3; }
    trap release_lock EXIT

    # Call the main function (not included in this snippet)
    main 200>&-
) 200>"${LOCK_FILE}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't remove the file; just let the process holding the file open exit.

```
(
    if [[ -n $LOGFILE ]]; then
        exec >>"$LOGFILE" 2>&1
    fi

    flock -xn 200 || { show_message "$(basename ${0}): cannot acquire lock ${LOCK_FILE}"; exit 3; }

    main
) 200>"${LOCK_FILE}"
```

When `main` exists, the subshell that opened `$LOCK_FILE` will exit as well, and the lock will be dropped.

If you want to release the lock explicitly, use `flock --unlock 200` instead of removing the file.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it seems I do actually need the trap/release_lock to release the lock on logout -- but using `--unlock` seems to relasee the lock correctly. Will be testing this before I set this question to "answered".